# Portlet not deploying to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, portlet

Ever since adding the `liferay-plugin-package.xml` and the `liferay-portlet.xml` I was told it was missing my portlet is not in my list of applications now like it used to i have been having issues with the porlet not working but it would at least show up in my list of applications but now it just seems to be missing

***liferay-plugin-package.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<plugin-package>
<name>WebApplication6</name>
    <module-id>liferay/WebApplication6/5.2.2.1/war</module-id>
    <types>
        <type>Portlet</type>
    </types>
    <short-description></short-description>
    <long-description></long-description>
    <change-log></change-log>
        <page-url>http://www.liferay.com</page-url>
        <author>Liferay, Inc.</author>
        <licenses>
                <license osi-approved="true">MIT</license>
        </licenses> 
        <liferay-versions>
            <liferay-version>5.2.3+</liferay-version>
        </liferay-versions>
</plugin-package>
```

***liferay-portlet.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>WebApplication6</portlet-name>
        <instanceable>True</instanceable>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Below is what appears in my lumnins.log file when i go to deploy my portlet war file to my test server.

```
2013-06-26 11:18:46,879 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Undeploying context [/WebApplication6]
2013-06-26 11:18:47,302 WARN  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Error while removing context [/WebApplication6]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.destroy(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4354)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-06-26 11:18:47,321 WARN  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Error during context [/WebApplication6] destroy
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.destroy(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4354)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroy(ContainerBase.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.destroy(StandardContext.java:4454)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1013)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-06-26 11:18:47,518 ERROR [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext error stopping 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.destroy(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4354)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.preDeregister(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.preDeregister(BaseModelMBean.java:1372)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.preDeregisterInvoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1048)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:421)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:403)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.Registry.unregisterComponent(Registry.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3999)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:890)
    at com.sghe.luminis.startup.ControlledDeployHostConfig.deployApps(ControlledDeployHostConfig.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1218)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-06-26 11:18:51,474 ERROR [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener Creation of the naming context failed: javax.naming.NamingException: Context is read only
2013-06-26 11:21:21,424 WARN  [ThreadPoolExecutor_46] com.liferay.util.servlet.SharedSessionWrapper Wrapped session is null
2013-06-26 11:21:37,594 WARN  [http-8443-Processor23] com.liferay.portal.servlet.ImageServlet Get a default image for 0
2013-06-26 11:21:53,345 WARN  [http-8443-Processor24] org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!*emphasized text**emphasized text**emphasized text*
```

Portlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<portlet-app xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd' version='2.0'>
    <portlet>
        <description>WebApplication6</description>
        <portlet-name>WebApplication6</portlet-name>
        <display-name>WebApplication6</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.test.WebApplication6</portlet-class>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <resource-bundle>com.test.messages</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>WebApplication6</title>
            <short-title>WebApplication6</short-title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Comment: With this declaration, you probably have a portlet declaration in your portlet.xml with the portlet id "WebApplication6". Are you really on 5.2.2 or 5.2.3? Would you consider upgrading?

Comment: yep i do have a portlet.xml (posted it above).  I guess so, i was just given a virtual server to work on for portlet development when i started work